# C# Unit testing - check if a private method was reached

Tags: c#, moq

I am using C# MOQ library.

Lets say I want to create a `UnitTest` for this piece of code:

```
if(condition){
    privateMethod();
}
else{
    logger.info("didn't hit")
}
```

I want to check if `privateMethod` was hit, I can't use the `Verify` function as it is private. How can I do that?

I thought about adding a `Status` member dedicated for the unit testing, which will hold the last location before exiting the tested method.

Comment: Could the access of this `privateMethod` be eventually changed to `protected`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847463/using-moq-to-verify-execution-of-private-methods

Comment: If you want to test a call of method you have to extract your private method to a new class and mock it. Otherwise you should focus on the effects of your private method. Example: if your methods writes some data to a file you can check for the file to be created

Comment: @Grappachu But if the methods writes some data to a file we have left unit test and doing integration test and the class itself is not valid for unit test

Comment: @SirRufo you're right, i didn't choose a top example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't test private methods. They are private implementation details of the class. You should only test the results of executing public methods.

> Properly designed SOLID code will never put you in a position which will require you to do private mocking.

Depending on whether you want to change your design or not, there are few approaches you could take:

- don't try to mock private details, focus on public API (doesn't help with design issue)
- extract private method to class, introduce dependency (long-term solution, improves design and makes code easily testable)
- make private method protected, override in test (doesn't help with design issue, might not yield valuable test)

Whichever you chose I leave up to you. However, I'll emphasize it one more time - *mocking private method* is not unit testing, library or tools problem - it is a **design problem** and is best solvable as such.

Comment: Although the things you have written about unit testing the private method are correct, it doesn't answers OP's question. As OP want to know a way to find out if the call to his private method is made or not, from the public method he is testing.

Comment: This class is a `Manager`, and this method is his start point. So it has some private logic which cannot be `Mocked`. So what i want to test here is for example: make sure the manager initiates the right amount of workers, etc. Maybe its not current to unit test such method?

Comment: I have given you 3 alternatives to what you can do. My suggestion is to inject another unit as a dependency that does all those things, or maybe even make the method protected and override it.

Answer (score 1):

I use MSTest and this is the solution I use in the Test Class to invoke Private Method:

```
Class target = new Class();
PrivateObject obj = new PrivateObject(target);
var retVal = obj.Invoke("PrivateMethod");
Assert.AreEqual(retVal);
```

It use the [PrivateObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.aspx) Class

Comment: This q is not on how to call a private method but how to detect if a private method was called